# A specific analytic integration can not be done

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

The following definite integral can not be done in "Matlab R2013a", although it can be done analytically in other mathematics programs. Why?

```
 syms r M c real
 assume(M>0)
 assume(c>M)
 y=1/(sqrt((r^2-M)*(r^2/c^2-1))*r);
 int(y,r,c,inf)
```

**The answer is**

```
atanh(sqrt(M)/c)/sqrt(M).
```

Thanks

Comment: Different programs have different symbolic integration routines. One succeeds, another fails -- nothing unusual.

Comment: How can I calculate this specific integration in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to write the solution:

```
-log((-M-c^2+2*sqrt(M)*c)/(M-c^2))/(2*sqrt(M))
```

I don't use Matlab, but can you try assuming that M does not equal c^2?